# Looping through a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON file that looks similar to this:

```
{
"Pages":{
        "/":{
            "Name": "Home",
            "Page": "index.php"
        },

        "/_admin":{
            "Name": "Admin",
            "Page": "_admin/index.php",

            "Template": "admin",
            "MobileTemplate": "admin-mobile",

            "Pages":{

                "/settings":{
                    "Name": "Settings",
                    "Page": "_admin/settings/index.php",
                    "Config": "_admin/settings/config.php",

                    "Pages":{

                        "/user":{
                            "Name": "Users",
                            "Page": "_admin/settings/user.php",
                            "Config": "_admin/settings/config.php",
                            "CatchAll": true
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        },

        "/tasdf":{
            "Name": "fs",
            "Page": "index.php"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to loop through this array (I have used JSON decode to turn it into PHP), and for every block of "Pages" I want to add extra data.

For example, the working should look like this:

```
Array Loop Starts
Finds "Pages"
    -Goes through "/"
    -No "Pages" - continue
   - Goees through "/_admin"
       -Finds "Pages"
       -Goes through "/settings"
           -Finds "Pages"
           -Goes Through "/user"
           -No Pages Continue
   - Goes through "/tasdf"
   - No "Pages" - continue
 End Loop
```

Everytime it goes through a part, I want it to merge with another array.

I am struggling writing code to see it keep looping everytime it finds the word "Pages" as the key. I have attempted many times but keep scrapping my code.

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: you are trying to give an assignment to us?

Comment: No assignment, its a personal project. I just can't get this multidimensional array loop working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a recursive function that scans your array to a depth of `n`. Something like this could work:

```
function findPagesInArray($myArray) {
    foreach($myArray as $index => $element) {
        // If this is an array, search deeper
        if(gettype($element) == 'array') {
            findPagesInArray($element);
        }

        // Reached the Pages..
        if($index == 'Pages') {
            // Do your task here
        }
    }
}
```

And you would now use it by calling `findPagesInArray($json_object)`

Comment: Will that work?  It seems that both the if condition and the elseif condition will be true at the same time (ie, all $elements with $index == 'Pages' are arrays).  Perhaps you need 2 ifs?