# Looping Through Multi-Dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've looked up a bunch of similar examples but still can't seem to figure out how loop through and echo the values from this array. Should be simple, but I'm dense. Help is appreciated.

```
array(2) { ["legend_size"]=> int(1) ["data"]=> array(2) { ["series"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "2014-01-17" [1]=> string(10) "2014-01-18" } ["values"]=> array(1) { ["Begin Session"]=> array(2) { ["2014-01-17"]=> int(1073) ["2014-01-18"]=> int(1122) } } } }
```

I'm trying to return the int values for the "values" array.

Comment: Have you tried recursion with type checking?  This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917022/looping-through-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: @josh-austin You can probably tell from the question itself I'm pretty novice, so recursion is out of my league right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the name of your array is, for the sake of example, `$mdarr`, and that the construction of the array is going to be roughly the same every time, it is as simple as:

```
$values_i_want = $mdarr['data']['values'];
```

If the values array you are looking for is going to be in different array depths in different cases, recursion combined with type checking will do the trick:

```
//returns values array or nothing if it's not found
function get_values_array($mdarr) {
    foreach ($mdarr as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == 'values') {
            return $val;
        } else if (is_array($val)) {
            return get_values_array($val);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as a base. I reconstructed your array so I could mess around with it.

```
$turtle = array('legend_size' => 'int(1)', 'data' =>array('series' => array('string(10) "2014-01-17"', '[1]=> string(10) "2014-01-18"'), 'values' => array('Begin_Session' =>array('2014-01-17' => 'int(1073)', '2014-01-18' => 'int(1122)'))));

// This is where you "navigate" the array by using [''] for each new array you'd like to traverse. Not sure that makes much sense, but should be clear from example.
foreach ($turtle['data']['values']['Begin_Session'] as $value) {
    $match = array();
// This is if you only want what's in the parentheses. 
    preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $value, $match);
    echo $match[1] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array structure is not going to change, and you just want the int values inside `values`, you could do the following:

```
//Create array
$some_array = array( 
    "legend_size" => 5, 
    "data" => array( 
        "series" => array(0 => "2014-01-17", 1 => "2014-01-18" ) 
        "values" => array(
            "Begin Session" => array("2014-01-17" => 1000, "2014-01-18" => 1000)
        )
    )
);

//Get values
foreach($some_array['data']['values'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        echo $key . " => ";

        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
        {
             echo "   " . $key2 . " => " . $value2;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo $key . " => " . $value;
    }
}
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
Begin Session =>
    2014-01-17 => 1000
    2014-01-18 => 1000
```